# Vue 3 : How to add the vuetify aliases in a npm package of a component

Tags: vuejs3, npm-package, vuetifyjs3

I am using vuetify 3 in my vue 3 project. I have defined aliases and defaults :

./src/plugins/vuetify.ts

```
...
export default createVuetify({
  aliases: {
    MyBtn: VBtn,
  },
  defaults: {
    VTextField: {
      variant: "underlined",
    },
    MyBtn: {
      size: "small",
    },
  },
});
```

This is working in the project containing the file. But I don't know how to have these styles still applied when I publish the component as an npm package, and import it in another project.

This is my current npm package configuration :

./lib/main.js

```
import MyComponent from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";
export { MyComponent };
```

./package.json

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/my-component.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/my-component.es.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src/types"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/my-component.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/my-component.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
}
```

./vite.config.ts

```
...
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "lib/main.js"),
      name: "MyComponent",
      fileName: (format) => `my-component.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

How can I "export" the aliases and defaults from my `./src/plugins/vuetify.ts` file to have them rendered  when I import my component in another project ?

Thank you

Comment: If another project imports your published project, how is it meant to use Vuetify?

Comment: I don't want the another project to have to do anything more than just importing the npm package, and have the component looking like what it is supposed to be

Comment: Same here Any Update !
I update my vite.config to the following but still not works !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with adding the vuetify component and exporting it with the `as` keyword like this

```
// lib.ts (file for exporting the stuff)
import { VBtn } from "vuetify/components";

export {
    VBtn as VBtnPrimary,
    VBtn as VBtnSecondary
};
```

in my lib.ts file (or your ./lib/main.js). In your case change the name VBtnPrimary to MyBtn.

I think, with the correct vite settings you can exclude the vuetify components, so that you just export the stuff, that you really need.

The bad thing is, I have to add that component in my imports in the project, where I use that library. But at least Visual Studio Code detect the component and gives you intelli sense.

```
// example vue component
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VBtnPrimary, VBtnSecondary } from 'my-vuetify-lib'
</script>
```